# Get the url of custom login page in the registration page

Tags: login, user-registration

I am having trouble in getting the url of the page from where I click the register link.

Scenario:

The url of the login page is:

> http://abcd.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fabcd.com%2Fxtreme%2F&page=1406

And I when I click register link it should add the redirect_to link in the register page like this:

> http://abcd.com/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fabcd.com%2Fxtreme%2F&page=1406

I have used the following code but its not taking redirect_to parameter:

```
add_action( 'registration_redirect', 'redirection_link' );
function redirection_link( $redirect_to ) {
  wp_redirect($GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS']['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track; just add a filter (not action!) to your `functions.php` and pass in the `redirect_to` parameter (no need for `wp_redirect`). As soon as the user has submitted the registration form, there will be a redirect to the new page:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'redirection_link' );
function redirection_link( $redirect_to ) {
    return $redirect_to . 'xtreme/page=1406';
}
```

Update: To perform a hard/permanent redirect to another page you can go with an [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) like this:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'redirection_link' );
function redirection_link( ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://abcd.com/xtreme/page=1406', 301 );
    // wp_redirect( home_url( '/xtreme/page=1406' ), 301 );
    exit;
}
```

Update 2: You can also pass in additional parameters (e.g. `redirect_to`) if you modify the default `register_url`:

```
add_filter( 'register_url', 'custom_register_url' );
function custom_register_url( $register_url ) {
    $register_url = home_url( '/wp-login.php/?action=register&redirect_to=http://abcd.com/xtreme/page=1406' );
    return $register_url;
}
```

Update 3: You can update/reset the `registration_redirect` to your new `register_url` (from Update 2) like this:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'reset_redirection_link' );
function reset_redirection_link() {
    return wp_registration_url();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i don't want the link to appear after the user has registered.I want it to appear on the action=register or registration page....when the register link is clicked on the login page.

Comment: @ParthKumar Okay, sorry, I've updated my answer with the fix! I think this will do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks for replying back but i have already tried this.The url changes what i wanted ...but results in an error saying too many redirects

Comment: Try to redirect to `home_url( '/' )` first to validate that it is working at all; are you redirecting your `page=1406`, too (e.g. via `.htaccess`)?

Comment: Its working perfectly fine for the home_url('/') as well as for
http://abcd.com/wp-login.php but not working for anything given as 'http://abcd.com/wp-login.php?*'...ie after the ? mark it is displaying same error ...too many redirects. And i am not doing anything in htaccess

Comment: Ups, you are right! The `?action=register` is already performing a redirect, but I've added a way to modify the default `register_url` in my answer! Hope this helps :)

Comment: you got it right...but there is now a new problem because of this...after registering its getting redirected to the home_url rather than the default registration page itself

Comment: I added a way to update/reset the `registration_redirect`. You can specify any redirect after the `return` (also check the very first snippet in my answer)

Comment: The page id is dynamic..so can you suggest some wordpress function to get the page_id value.
Note: url_to_postid( $url ); only works when ?page_id=N whereas i want ?action=register&page_id=N...

Comment: How is your dynamic ID related to `?action=register`? Did you try `get_the_ID()`? Perhaps you can ask this in detail in another question as it seems to be a different problem?

Comment: ok,sorry..i want to just get the return value in a different php file using this filter...Is there anyway i can access this return value in other file..

Comment: Yes, you can return/echo the parameter via `$_GET['redirect_to'];` :)